# Recovering "My Pictures" folder on Windows using Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, data-recovery

My windows partition got infected with a virus so I can't boot in Windows. I am trying to recover some documents from the windows partition by booting Ubuntu on my dual boot system. I was successful in easily recovering some files from my desktop. However, I can't get the files from my pictures folder. Here's what I see (after blocking the username):

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -alth /host/Users/XXXXX/Documents/My*
lrwxrwxrwx 2 root root 116 2010-12-06 09:09 /host/Users/XXXXX/Documents/My Videos -> /root/Users/XXXXX/Videos
lrwxrwxrwx 2 root root 124 2010-12-06 09:09 /host/Users/XXXXX/Documents/My Pictures -> /root/Users/XXXXX/Pictures
lrwxrwxrwx 2 root root 112 2010-12-06 09:09 /host/Users/XXXXX/Documents/My Music -> /root/Users/XXXX/Music
root@ubuntu:~# cd /host/Users/XXXXX/Documents/My\ Pictures 
bash: cd: /host/Users/XXXXX/Documents/My Pictures: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:~# cd /root
root@ubuntu:~# ls
root@ubuntu:~#
```

If I try to open it by clicking it in Ubuntu's places window, it displays a window saying

> The Link "My Pictures" is Broken. Move it to Trash?
>
> This link cannot be used, because its target
>   "/root/Users/XXXXX/Pictures" doesn't exist.

How can I access my pictures?

**Update:**

I have a wubi installation. Firther, If I look in `/host/Users/XXXX/Pictures`:

```
root@ubuntu:~# cd /host/Users/XXXXX/Pictures/ 
root@ubuntu:/host/Users/XXXXX/Pictures# ls -alth
total 29K 
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28K 2011-08-13 13:58 .. 
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   0 2011-05-01 16:07 .
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 504 2011-05-01 16:07 desktop.ini 
root@ubuntu:/host/Users/XXXXXPictures# cat desktop.ini  
�� 
[.ShellClassInfo] 
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21779
InfoTip=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-12688 
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-113 
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll IconIndex=-236
```

Answer (score 1):

The links should point to

```
/host/Users/XXXXX/Videos
/host/Users/XXXXX/Pictures
/host/Users/XXXX/Music
```

so take a look there.

Also, you have a WUBI installation, you should mention that.

**Edit**

If you do not find your pictures there, you can find for them with the command

```
find /media/data -iname '*.jpg' | sed 's|/[^/]*$||' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | less
```

that will list the directories where there are pictures, sorted for number of pictures contained.

Also, you should check if there are other partitions where your pictures could be. To begin you can do `sudo fdisk -l` to see disks and partitions.

Comment: Thanks! Those folders do exist, but I can't find my pictures there. Are the actual files somewhere else?

Comment: @highBandWidth: you can search for them with the command `find /host -iname '*.jpg'`.

Comment: the find results in so many results that its hard to find where to look. Though I couldn't find it so far. Most of the entries are from the Internet cache and installed applications.

Comment: @highBandWidth: see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a [Ubuntu live disc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD). Wubi might not have enough access.

If you booted up with a live disc, easily click on your `X GB disk` in GNOME's **Places** menu. That mounts your HDD. *(If it displays any error message, comment here with the message!)*

Then, push <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gksudo nautilus /media`. Your HDD must be there, if you didn't get an error message during the mounting.

*Optionally press <kbd>F3</kbd>, if you want to display 2-side browsing.*

Click on the folder in the `/media`, then copy the data to an USB device, or somewhere else in your LAN.

I hope, it helps. Comment, if you have any questions.